# InputMismatchException is not catching

Tags: java

I am having difficulty getting the InputMismatchException to catch when the user enters a string value instead of an int or double. I use a set method to set the keyboard input to a variable inside of the CompCalc class and I am not sure if that is where the problem lies. I've tried numerous things but to no avail. I can use a Do/While loop to achieve the desired result; however, I am new to programming and would like to successfully implement the Try/Catch in this scenario.

Here is the main class:

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 *
 * @author shawnwilliams
 */

public class EmpComp {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        CompCalc compensation = new CompCalc();

        System.out.println("This program will calculate your total "
                + "compensation for the prior year.");
        System.out.println("Enter your total sales: ");


        try 
        {
        compensation.setTotalSales(keyboard.nextDouble());           
        } 
        catch (InputMismatchException e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
            keyboard.next();
        }

        System.out.printf("\nYour total compensation for this year is: "
                + "%.2f\n\n ", compensation.getTotalComp());
    }

}
```

This is the compensation calculator class

```
public class CompCalc {
    private final double salary = 50000.00,
                         commissionRate = 0.02;

    private double totalSales,
                   totalCommission,
                   totalComp;

    public void setTotalSales( double s ) 
    {
        totalSales = s;
    }

    public double getTotalSales()
    {
        return totalSales;
    }

    public double getTotalCommission() 
    {
        return totalCommission;
    }

    public double getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public double getCommissionRate() 
    {
        return commissionRate;
    }

    public double getTotalComp()
    {
        totalComp = totalSales * commissionRate + salary;
        return totalComp;
    }

}
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at EmpComp.main(EmpComp.java:33)
```

Thanks in advance!

Shawn

Comment: Is the problem that if you enter an invalid response, it throws the exception and doesn't ask again?

Comment: using a while loop is the correct way to do it. you can use try/catch inside the loop.

Comment: Correct, the exception is still being thrown despite the catch statement. I am mainly working on the catch for now. Am I correct to assume I will have to put the entire try/catch into a while loop to prompt the user for updated input?

Comment: yes, as i said, without while loop, you're not going to get a repetition of getting the next input.

Comment: @yarivt What I meant in the post was that I could achieve the same result using a Do/While without the try/catch in it. I am having trouble getting the improper input type to trigger the catch.

Comment: @ShawnWilliams see my answer. are you getting the mismatch if you're not providing a double?

Comment: is this the entire code? line 33 which throws this exception is `System.out.printf`. have you debugged this code?

Comment: Yes, this is the entire code. The code compiles and runs without error as long as an int or double is entered by the user. When I enter a string, the InputMismatchException is thrown but it is not caught by the try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you in general.

```
boolean ok = false;
while(!ok) {
    try {
        compensation.setTotalSales(keyboard.nextDouble());
        ok = true;
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number.");
        keyboard.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: That still throws an exception. I had tried placing it in a while loop with while(keyboard.hasNext()), but that wasn't working for me either. The exception is not being caught.

Comment: it think your question isnt clear, which exception is being thrown? please provide the stack trace for the exception

Answer (score 0):

I discovered where the problem was. The problem wasn't in the code I was writing, but in the way I was compiling the code in Netbeans. I am required to use an IDE for this assignment and I wasn't familiar enough with how Netbeans compiles files and builds projects. I recognized this when I compiled the main class file in the command line and everything worked as intended. I wasted time trying to figure out a problem that didn't exist.

Thanks for your time @yarivt!